# LDAP connectivity from Team foundation server 2018

Tags: tfs, ldap

Is is possible to authenticate TFS2018 (installed in a separate server) users with LDAP (installed in a different server). If only AD needs to be installed in TFS server, then how to import users from LDAP to AD so that the users can be authenticated in TFS.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that TFS only supports AD and it's required in TFS setup.

Since LDAP server doesn't have Active Directory, I don't think TFS can work with it.

Whatever, you can have a try with installing a Domain Controller (not on the same server as TFS) and Sync it with LDAP...

LDAP Account Synchronization Project
http://acctsync.sourceforge.net/

Comment: hi Thanks for your reply..The Active directory is already setup in the other server. When a user login to TFS server , the authentication needs to happen with the remote Active drectory...

Comment: Has the TFS machine been added to the domain?

Comment: No. it is not joined to domain , it is in workgroup only.

Comment: I am afraid you have to add it to the domain, otherwise you can only use the local users.